# PL/SQL Member of with multicolumn record

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

How can I use `member of` with a multicolumn collection?

Tried this:

```sql
declare
   TYPE t_ref_by_email_rec IS RECORD (
           email varchar(100)
         , ref   number
   );
   TYPE t_ref_by_email IS TABLE OF t_ref_by_email_rec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
   v_ref_by_email t_ref_by_email := t_ref_by_email();
begin
   if 'email@domain.com' member of v_ref_by_email.email then
      -- Do something
   end if;
end;
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way, because `member of` is an equality condition for an array element and has no scope for a partial match, and the best you can do is query it as an SQL table.

Comment: Do you understand the differences between "associative array" on the one hand, and "nested table" on the other hand? They are different collection data types. `MEMBER OF` is defined only for nested tables, but the collection type you defined is an associative array. So, the simple answer to your question is that it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

- The `MEMBER OF` operator is only valid for collection data types.
- `TYPE identifier IS TABLE OF type1 INDEX BY type2` is not a collection; it is an associative array.
- `TYPE identifier IS TABLE OF type1` is how you define a collection.

However, even then you cannot use `MEMBER OF` on a partial attribute of a collection; you would need to use it to match an entire collection element (and it did not appear to work with a record).

Instead, you can use a loop:

```
DECLARE
   TYPE t_ref_by_email_rec IS RECORD (
           email varchar(100)
         , ref   number
   );
   TYPE t_ref_by_email IS TABLE OF t_ref_by_email_rec;
   v_ref_by_email t_ref_by_email := t_ref_by_email(
     t_ref_by_email_rec( 'a@b', 1 ),
     t_ref_by_email_rec( 'c@d', 2 ),
     t_ref_by_email_rec( 'e@f', 3 ),
     t_ref_by_email_rec( 'g@h', 4 )
   );
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. v_ref_by_email.COUNT LOOP
    IF 'e@f' <> v_ref_by_email(i).email THEN
      CONTINUE;
    END IF;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Found' );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```